# Host local database using ubuntu for external applications

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am trying to build an Android application and I need to install a database to store all my data like users, passwords etc. This is the first time when I do something like this and I dont have a clue about what i should do. I have seen that there is a way to use lamp  but seems quite complicate and i am not familiar to php. Is there any other solution?

Comment: would it not be more logical to use android version for sqlite? http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

LAMP would be overkill. That is intended for hosting a website.

If you only need a database you can install MySQL. But that might be overkill too. There is also SQLite (it is a "light" database and I would opt for that).

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

[SQLite](https://sqlite.org/):

```
sudo apt-get sqlite
```

> SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

---

MySQL Workbench can used for MySQL administration:

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

SQLiteman can be used for sqlite3 administration:

[image]

```
sudo apt-get sqliteman
```